# C/C++ how to combine multiple arrays/lists of strings?

Tags: c++, c, string, list, combinations

I have 5 lists containing strings: append, word, middle, combo, prepend. (or s0,s1,s2,s3,s4).
Each list can randomly contain 0 to 256 strings on program start.

How can I output all possible combinations?

I tried a cascade of for() loops, but this fails if a list in the middle contains 0 strings (eg s2).

Comment: use `sprintf`, yet question is not very much clear to me.

Comment: Probably it fails because you do not handle a corner case. Please post your code so we can see what you do wrong.

Comment: 5 lists of string or a list of 5 strings ?

Comment: My first question is why? In the case of 5 lists of 256 strings you're looking at north of 1 trillion combinations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use `std::vector<string> s1,s2,s3,s4,s5;`
If you like ugly code:

```
int i = 1;
for (auto itr1 = s1.begin(), end1 = s1.end(); itr1 != end1; ++itr1)
    for (auto itr2 = s2.begin(), end2 = s2.end(); itr2 != end2; ++itr2)
        for (auto itr3 = s3.begin(), end3 = s3.end(); itr3 != end3; ++itr3)
            for (auto itr4 = s4.begin(), end4 = s4.end(); itr4 != end4; ++itr4)
                for (auto itr5 = s5.begin(), end5 = s5.end(); itr5 != end5; ++itr5)
                    std::cout<<"solution "<<i++<< ": "<< *itr1 << " - " << *itr3<< " - " << *itr4<< " - " << *itr5 <<std::endl;
```

Its not elegant, but won't fail when sX.size()==0.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put an if to check if the list is empty or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume with your example that you want to permute the words in an array

And since C++ is tagged, I'd prefer following (using `vector` of `string`)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{

    std::vector <std::string> v ={ "append", "word", 
                       "middle", "combo", "prepend"};

    //Use v.push_back to add any number of strings

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    do {
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                  std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    } while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}
```

and I'm pretty sure that you already know that for 256 string you gonna wait till **`256!`**